# Convert Ternary Expression to a Binary Tree

Tags: java, recursion, tree

This is programming question I came across (geeksforgeeks) : 
Given a string that contains ternary expressions. The expressions may be nested, task is convert the given ternary expression to a binary Tree.Any feedback appreciated.

All the required classes are added as members.
I am using a simple recursive approach to build the tree. 
Each time  a '?' expression is encountered then the next element is added as the left node.Similarly, each time a ':' expression is encountered then the next element is added as the right node.

```
 Input :  string expression =   a?b:c 
    Output :        a
                  /  \
                 b    c

    Input : expression =  a?b?c:d:e
    Output :     a
               /  \
              b    e
            /  \
           c    d
```

The Code:

```
public class TernaryExpressionToBinaryTree {

    public class Node {
        private Character data;
        private Node left;
        private Node right;

        public Node(Character data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    public class BST {
        public Node getRoot() {
            return root;
        }

        public void setRoot(Node root) {
            this.root = root;
        }

        public Node root;

        public void addNode(Character data) {
            root = addNode(root, data);
        }

        private Node addNode(Node node, Character data) {
            if (node == null) {
                return new Node(data);
            }
            if (data < node.data) {
                node.left = addNode(node.left, data);
            } else {
                node.right = addNode(node.right, data);
            }
            return node;
        }
    }

    /*
    Preorder traversal
     */
    public void displayTree(Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
            System.out.print(node.data + " | ");
            displayTree(node.left);
            displayTree(node.right);
        }
    }
    public Node buildTreeFromTernaryExpression(Node node, String expression, int index) {

        // check corner cases
        if (expression == null || expression.trim().isEmpty() || index < 0 || index > expression.length()) {
            return null;
        }
       // if its is a valid character
        if (node == null || index == 0 || expression.charAt(index) != '?' || expression.charAt(index) != ':') {
            node = new Node(expression.charAt(index));
        }
      //if it is a valid expression ? or :
        if ((index + 1) < expression.length()-1 && expression.charAt(index + 1) == '?') {
            node.left = buildTreeFromTernaryExpression(node.left, expression, index + 2);
        }

        if ((index + 1) < expression.length()-1 && expression.charAt(index + 1) == ':') {
            node.right = buildTreeFromTernaryExpression(node.right, expression, index + 2);
        }
        return node;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TernaryExpressionToBinaryTree ternaryExpressionToBinaryTree = new TernaryExpressionToBinaryTree();
        Node root = ternaryExpressionToBinaryTree.buildTreeFromTernaryExpression(null, "a?b?c:d:e", 0);
        ternaryExpressionToBinaryTree.displayTree(root);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can delete the `BST` class. You don't use it anywhere.
2. Error handling looks weird to me. I suggest throwing an exception if the input is invalid. You also don't check all possible cases. For instance, you code prints a tree `? | a | b |` for the input `??a:b`, which is clearly invalid. I'd recommend either adding proper error handling or just dropping it altogether (the problem statement says that the string is a ternary expression, anyway).
3. Comments should not repeat the code. If you have something like `// if it is a valid character`, it's a good indicator that the following check should be moved to a separate method with a proper name (something like `private boolean isValidCharacter(Node node, String expression, int index)`.

Comment: Are `TernaryExpressionToBinaryTree`, `ternaryExpressionToBinaryTree`, and `buildTreeFromTernaryExpression` acceptable as variable/class/method names? they seem to pollute the code and are quite long.

Comment: @ljeabmreosn The name should accurately reflect the  purpose of a class/method. It's fine that it's long.